# Should a Brahmin strictly follow vedas?

Tags: vedas, philosophy

Should a Brahmin or a normal person strictly follow vedas to attain good birth or to attain Moksha.

Comment: Moksha = 100 marks. Svarga = 50 marks. Bhumi = 25 marks. Naraka = 0 marks. Depending on what you want, you can follow Vedas strictly or liberally.

Comment: @mar can you answer it